# Assembly: How to dynamically load an Assembly that also depends on another assembly in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reflection, .net-assembly

I want the main app to be able to load `plugin1.dll` which has dependency on

`PlugingCore.dll` but when I try using `Assembly.LoadFile("c:\plugin1.dll");` I get an error:

**('((System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly)a).DefinedTypes' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException')**

**Note: both PluginCore.dll and Plugin1.dll are in same directory.**

Comment: hvae you tried with `Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\plugin1.dll")`?

Comment: see if [assembly (error: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23717112/3796048) solves your problem

Comment: Copy the exception details and add them to your question. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/

Comment: I found the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15093022/2766753.
btw thank you @damith :)

That is step 1 solve.
Is there any way it can be done by using `Assembly.Load()` method instead?

Comment: If you can modify main application please add AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event. The reason why dependency is not loaded is that it simply resides in folder other than main application. Please refer i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5262129/7047935